# "protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl" in Ubuntu14.10

Tags: ubuntu, curl

When I executed the following command in ubuntu14.10, it posted an error `"protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl"`:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9554/q/backup/in/rabbit -d type=rabbitmq \
-d url=amqp://127.0.0.1 -d queue=backup -d exchange=incoming
```

But i can successfully execute this command:

`curl http://127.0.0.1:9554/q/backup -d maxSize=10g`

I don't know what went wrong. Even though i had upgraded `curl` version `7.37` to `7.51`, it didn't work. Could someone give some clues?

Comment: Why not upgrade to a up-to-date version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version `curl-7.51.0` from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download/) then compile it as follows:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.51.0.tar.gz
tar xvf curl-7.51.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.51.0
./configure --with-ssl
make
sudo make install
```